# Could more Earth-like planets exist in our Sun's "goldilocks" zone?

Tags: planets, astronomy, solar-system

These planets would be similar in size to Earth. Mars and Venus don't need to exist in this scenario.

So how many Earth-like worlds can be squeezed into the sun's "goldilocks" zone? Mars and Venus like worlds can be ignored.

Comment: If Mars and Venus didn't exist wouldn't there be fewer planets in the "goldilocks" zone not more?

Comment: Vote close because this isn't about world building but actually an astronomy question. Plus I swear its a duplicate but am to lazy to go digging.

Comment: Don't think this is off-topic, it seems to be asking about the plausibility of having planets in this <grimace> "Goldilocks" zone. What's not world-building about that? If it really is a duplicate then that's another story...

Comment: I'm definitely inclined to agree with @colmde above; this is about our solar system (or something very much like it), but it's certainly about an imaginary variation of it, so it seems to me to be a good fit for Worldbuilding. I'm pretty certain it'd be shot over our way for being too hypothetical if asked over on Astronomy, which is the other natural site in the network to ask this type of question.

Comment: If you are wondering how many planets can have stable orbits inside the goldlock zone of our sun, the number is probably more than the 3 we have and even more if you allow to manually place the planet instead of having to form them naturally. The more you add, the less likely they will have stable orbits but the "goldilock zone" is actually a huge space when used to talk about exoplanet's potential habitability.

Answer (score 8):

Having more than one planet in goldilocks zone is surely possible, after all our (real) Venus is just outside it and Mars is within.

Having more on very similar orbits is more complex due to possibly disruptive interactions between planets.

This may be easily overcome having several planets on the same orbit in L4/L5, the so called "Trojan" positions. These positions are very stable.

You can easily have two "trains" of planets well within the habitable zone.

Comment: Trojan stability requires mass rations of 10000, 100, 1 more or less.  The third body has to be much smaller (2 orders of magnitude) smaller.

Comment: Venus is inside the Goldilocks' zone of our sun. It's just that being in the Goldilocks zone is not enough to grant habitability.

Comment: @Rekesoft: you are right, of course. OP asked about goldilocks, not habitability.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: I was looking at [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#/media/File:Diagram_of_different_habitable_zone_regions_by_Chester_Harman.jpg) from wikipedia and Mars seems in the right zone, while Venus seems outside it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

It is all about stability. [Kolmogorov–Arnold–Moser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem) says that Solar system is mostly stable. Mostly is the key word. Even with current settings, if we run thousands billions year long simulation we will see some orbit instability([mostly it would be Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System#Laskar_.26_Gastineau)).

The closer you pack you planets, the worse it would be. You can put hundreds of planets there but in several years their orbits would deteriorate.

I met a rule of thumb that distance between planets should be about [10 Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) radius for long term stability(billions of years). If we assume Goldilock's zone size = 0.5 au then for Earth sized planets that would be 8-9 planets. Obviously that's quite unlikely to happen naturally.

Decision with putting a giant, and placing Earth sized planets in it's Lagrangian point would be less effective because giant planet has pretty big Hill sphere.

Comment: I think it's a safe assumption to say that the orbits would not deteriorate or otherwise the planets would not have been that way in the time it takes planets to form.  Therefore I think this is a fairly reasonable conclusion.

Comment: If you allow for some advanced civilization that can adjust the orbits of entire planets, then stability is much less of an issue.  Active control can counteract the random perturbations that the planets inflict on each other, allowing for very dense systems.  If the system forms naturally, then it may be highly unlikely for the system to be more dense then ours.

Comment: @Luke Yeah, if you allow adjusting for stability then you can just put thousands of Earths on single round orbit in Klemperer rosette pattern and put several rings like this in Goldilocks zone. In this case the max would be tens, even hundreds, thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  In our solar system the planets are on an exponentially increasing set of distances. (See Titus Bode Rule; Dermott's law) seems to show that orbital bodies are spread out in a power law.  Note that TB is now considered a coincidence. (I'm skeptical.  3 items is a coincidence. 6 is a not understood phenomenon.)

That said closely space planets will have similar periods, and will be near each other for relatively extended periods of time.  This allow for fairly large perturbations.  I suspect that there is some minimum ratio of orbital period to have long term stability.

Earth is just barely inside the zone, and if not for the greenhouse effect would likely be an ice ball (18 C colder)

It may be possible if you have a gas giant acting as a shepherd to keep orbits stable.  Or maybe that would be more disruptive.

You can get 2 planets by having them as a binary, tidally locked together.

You could have a massive planet in orbit, then a series of moons that were individually habitable.  This puts them still in an exponential series from the massive planet but effectively at the same distance from the sun.

Comment: Is the Titus-Bode Law really a law, in the sense that there's some physical reason for the spacing, or just reverse logic applied to chance spacing in the one planetary system we know of?  Do the moons of the gas giants (at least the ones that aren't captured asteroids) follow this law?  Also, Mars would probably be habitable if it had a mass & atmosphere similar to Earth's.

Comment: @jamesqf I distinctly recall someone applying Titus-Bode on the moons of at least one or two our solar system's gas giants, but I don't remember where at the moment. The bottom line there was that the math worked, if you allowed for gaps in the sequence.

Comment: Titius-Bode isn't a law, but a coincidence. Other solar systems that have been observed do not follow the same spacing, nor do the moons of Uranus or Jupiter. There are spacings based on orbital resonance, but there predictions of where extrasolar planets should be based on T-B rules have failed more often than not.

Comment: @jamesqf Keith points out that it's not a law.  My long ago astronomy courses not-withstanding.  I've edited my answer.  Power distributions can arise easily from conservation of angular momentum and scale invariance.

Comment: @KeithMorrison.  Edited in light of what you said.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a planet sharing exactly the same orbit with the Earth with 180 degree angular difference i.e. it is placed at the other side of the Sun. Then it looks impossible to detect such a planet at a glance. However, if such a planet really exists, then it is expected to change the calculated orbits of the space probes sent to Mars due to its gravity but no such anomaly is obsreved. Then the answer to the question is, almost 100%, no, unless it is really really a small body.

Comment: I don't believe the question is asking whether there *really are* more Earth-like planets in the Sun's habitable zone. Just whether it would be theoretically possible.

Comment: Then, it is going to be better to change my words "almost 100%, no" to "theoretically almost 100%, no" as the answer already discuss why it is theoretically "almost 100%, no"

Comment: It's not asking about out own solar system at all.  It's asking how many planets one could reasonably fit into the hypothetical goldilocks zone of a hypothetical sun-like star.

Comment: That would not be stable, and you end up with horseshoe orbits or a Lagrange point.  As for Earth, tou *would* see it because the orbit is eccentric.